# Extjs 5 move accordion Button to the left of title

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Quick question I can not seem to get the accordion button to move from the right to the left and was wondering is there a specific way of doing it i have checked the docs but can not seem to do it. I have added some code and I cant add a image due to lack of reputation.

[EDIT]

[image]

I want move the accordion button before the Title.

```
{
                          xtype: "panel",
                          id: "calendarLeftMenu",
                          layout: {
                              type: 'accordion',
                              titleCollapse: true,
                              animate: false,
                              activeOnTop: false,
                              multi: true,
                              buttonAlign:"left"
                          },
                          items: [
                            {
                                xtype: "panel",
                                title: "Releases",
                                left: "0px",
                                buttonAlign:"left",
                                id: "release-panel",
                                style: "padding-left: 1px;",
                                listeners: {
                                    beforeexpand: {
                                        fn: function () {
                                            if (Ext.get('release-on-btn').dom.className === 'switch-small-off-icon') {
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                tools: [
                                  {
                                      type: 'mytool',
                                      id: 'release-collapse-btn',
                                      renderTpl: releaseTabSwitcher,
                                      width: 60,
                                      region: "west",
                                      weight: 100,
                                  }
                                ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
                                header:{
                                    titlePosition: 1
                                },
```